# Data types between the Service (Application/Controller) and UI layers

Tags: language-agnostic, architecture

Consider the common layered architecture of:

- UI

  Service/Application/Controller

  Domain

  Persistancy

What should be the types between the Service and the UI layers?

Should the return types of the methods in the Service layer be **primitives**? Can they be **objects from the Domain layer**?

The motivation:
We are building a forum system. Somewhere in the Service layer there should be a method like "getForums". I am wondering what should be its return type -

- Should it be some collection of forumID's (primitives) - we would need to issue many more calls to the Service layer in order to present the topic and description of the forum (using its ID).

  Should it be some collection of Forum objects (from the domain layer) - we could end up with a UI that has direct access to the Domain layer (sounds really bad to me)

  Should it be some collection of specially made objects (representing only the topic, description and ID of a forum)? (sounds like too much code for nothing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Data Transfer Object pattern:

http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html

This would be implemented between the UI and the Service layer and can be tailored to the view of the data that the UI requires.

Comment: Thanks. This was actually what we finally did. Turned out to be a good choice :)